# Is there any way to query elasticsearch using curl for multiple documents to extract field values from _source?

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I am looking for curl queries to query multiple unique document ID's in the index. Like we know that the actual data for document is stored under "_source" but so far I am able to query the source for a single document_id for the required fields but not for multiple documents including a filter. I was of the opinion that 'mget' would be helpful here like

- GET ////_source

For eg -

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_index/document/id/_source?_source_include=_id_batch" -d "{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"_doc_date":"20150122"}}],"from": 0,"fields":[],"size":5,"sort":[]}" > "C:\Users\user.id\Downloads\output.json"
```

Sample Index -

[image: Index-Snap_shot]

Answer (score 1):

There is actually mget API:

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-get.html

Using your example, you could do something like:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/my_index/_mget' -d '{
    "docs" : [
        {
            "_type" : "document",
            "_id" : "1"
        },
        {
            "_type" : "document",
            "_id" : "2"
        }
    ]
}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sleigner, I looked at that page too and did a bit of ground work. But everything I thought of doing it, it looks like I have to insert the id's manually everytime. So I was looking for a more robust solution as the sample only had a couple of documents but my production design has around 90k. I am also researching on some scripts maybe which can help here.

Comment: Have you thought about empty search API? Empty search would return all result by default. E.g.: `curl 'localhost:9200/my_index/document/_search?size=1000'`. You could increase the size to get more results (but it would take longer to finish).

Comment: I did, but with that, I was not able to capture the whole set of batch_ids. I tried to specify the "fields": along with the filter condition but got only the filter part working and not the fetch of the batch_id's from _source.

Comment: If I correct understand your problem, you have documents, ant every document have bach_id. You need filter some documents, and get their bach_id's ? If I am correct, you should use aggregation by bach_id, it will return you all unique bach_id's